# SQL Server : which queries are executed?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an client application which shows me user info, products and prices etc from SQL Server via buttons on localhost.

For example, when I click on show expenses, it gets some information.

I want to learn which button executes which query?

Is there any way the monitor SQL statements which are executed by the app?

I tried

```
SELECT deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], dest.TEXT AS [Query]
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

but this code does not show SQL statements from app.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at Sql Server Profiler - http://www.techrepublic.com/article/step-by-step-an-introduction-to-sql-server-profiler/

Comment: Definitely check out **SQL Server Profiler** - that's ***THE*** tool for this job

Comment: Of course, if you're treating the application as a black box, there's no way for you to be sure, having captured 10 (or 100, 1000, etc) queries that the next time you run the application it won't run a completely different query. The only way to be sure is to examine the source code (and understand it)

Comment: @AshishGupta thank you, it works. also thank you Marc_s 

Damien_The_Unbeliever , i dont have source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally when you are using Sql Server Profiler, you get results for other databases as well when running the trace - If the same database server has other databases hosted which are used by other applications. You would want to track things in **your** database which **your** application is using. It may not be case for you If you have only one database in your database server - Just mentioning If this is the case. I have found this approach really useful.

I would set up a template with your database as filter and use that template to create the trace.

This is how you you create a template - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175070.aspx

This is how you filter to see the only the queries executed against your database :-

> Under Trace template properties > Events Selection tab > select show
>   all columns. Now under column filters, you should see the database
>   name. Enter the database name for the Like section and you should see
>   traces only for that database.

You can see the Sql statements executed by the application. I had the profiler running upfront. See an example below.

User enters name as "ashish1" in the below windows form :-

[image]

The code which gets executed when user hits the button :-

[image]

If you have the profiler running, you can see the Sql statement which was sent by the application:-
[image]

Comment: thank you for help. You explaind very well. But ı cant do it. It returns same output and do not return sql statments which is executed by client app.

Comment: @user2922744 - Not really. You can see the Sql statement executed by the application. Please see my updated answer above. Also - please upvote If this has helped you. :-)

Comment: LoginName :) I set the login name in the like section. It works

Comment: @user2922744 - Good thing. Once you have set up the template, you can use whatever filter which works for you.